# MongoDB sort collection by custom field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, database

I have aggregation query, that looks like this:

```
aggregate.append([
            {$sort: paginateOptions.sort},
            {$match: paginateOptions.match},
            {$skip: (paginateOptions.page - 1) * paginateOptions.limit},
            {$limit: paginateOptions.limit},
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'users',
                    localField: 'owner',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'owner'
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: '$owner',
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    name: {
                        $concat: ["$firstname", " ", "$lastname"]
                    },
                    email: 1,
                    owner: {
                        _id: 1,
                        username: 1
                    },
                    last_note: {
                        $arrayElemAt: ["$notes", -1]
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

I want to sort by the last note time field (last_note.time).
The problem is, that this field is created on the project process, and if I will add a sort after the project, I will get a sort only for the limit documents, not for the whole collection (because it will be after the limit and skip..)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should sort before skip and limit:

```
 `[
{$match: paginateOptions.match},
{$lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'owner',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'owner'
            }
        },
{$unwind: {
                path: '$owner',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
{$project: {
                name: {
                    $concat: ["$firstname", " ", "$lastname"]
                },
                email: 1,
                owner: {
                    _id: 1,
                    username: 1
                },
                last_note: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$notes", -1]
                }
            }
 },
 {$sort: paginateOptions.sort},
 {$skip: (paginateOptions.page - 1) * paginateOptions.limit},
 {$limit: paginateOptions.limit},
    ]`
```

Comment: this way the query's performance will be bad. The sort should be before the project, also the skip and limit, as from the mongodb docs